# Is there a way to simplify this code avoiding to call `onDestroy` manually each time?

Tags: svelte, addeventlistener, server-sent-events, removeeventlistener

We're using EventSource in multiple places in out SvelteKit app, like this:

```html
<script>
  import { onDestroy } from 'svelte';
  import { customEventSource } from '$lib/events';

  const callback = (event: MessageEvent) => {
    console.log('event:', event);
  };

  customEventSource.addEventListener('message', callback);

  onDestroy(() => {
    customEventSource.removeEventListener('message', callback);
  });
</script>
```

As you can see there is a lot to write each time.

Isn't there a magic way - as Svelte has taught us - to simplify?

Especially so I don't have to **manually** call `onDestroy` every time?

Comment: If you have SSR enabled, using global singleton state is a bad idea, it's shared across users/sessions on the server. This code should presumably be in `onMount` anyway, as it's meant to connect from the browser to the server (`onMount` can return an on-destroy function, so you just need `onMount`).

Comment: Also, please do not cross post your question on different platforms at the same time. You are wasting people's time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I imagine something like this will work:

```js
// This is a helper file.

import { onDestroy } from 'svelte'
import { customEventSource } from '$lib/events'

export function listenForMessages(listener){
   customEventSource.addEventListener('message', listener)
   onDestroy(() => customEventSource.removeEventListener('message', listener))
}
```

In your component:

```html
<script>
import { listenForMessages } from './the-file.js'

listenForMessages((event) => {
   console.log('event:', event)
})
</script>
```